# Are there still researches on new Data Structures? If so, what are some examples / scenarios?

Tags: data-structures, research

And I assume these new data structures are more context/field-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  For instance, you can look at the [SODA conference](https://dl.acm.org/conference/soda) to find several examples of research papers published on data structures.  Many of these are sophisticated and even esoteric.  The field is too broad to summarize here.

Comment: there is also new functional data structures as mentioned here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/whats-new-in-purely-functional-data-structures-since-okasaki/1550#1550